# bash: adb: command not found in Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, adb

I have installed **adb.exe** and other files and folders from `platform-tools` inside of `/c/adb/platform-tools/adb.exe` in a Windows 10 machine, but I am unclear as to what should happen next and a result I am not sure if it's a step I am missing or if the employer has put a block on the machine they issued to me.

What steps do I need to take to get `adb devices` working? This way if it still does not work then I know I need to let their IT team know they need to unblock whatever it is that is keeping me from utilizing `adb devices`.

There is this guide here: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator/

but the folder file structure is geared towards a unixy system and even when I run `./adb version` I get permission denied.

I went into environment variables and added to my `Path`: `C:\adb\platform-tools\adb.exe`, but when I run `adb devices` or `adb version` I still get `command not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use it from anywhere, you must add the folder in which adb is located to your PATH environment variable.

Otherwise without adding that, you can go to that folder on terminal ( cd /c/adb/platform-tools/adb.exe ) and use it from there.

Comment: I am still getting `bash: adb: command not found` even after adding `/c/adb/platform-tools/adb.exe` to my `Path`.

Comment: Did you open a new shell ( it doesnt take effect until a new shell is opened )?

Also based on the path written, seems you're using the WSL, and it may be that ENV variable needs a standard Windows style PATH, or is only valid in CMD Prompt / Powershell.  Experiment a bit!  ( Haven't used Windows/WSL in a long time, don't know the interactions between them )

Comment: your answer is a good one although after I added the correct path which is slightly different than what I shared in OP, the issue now is that the employer needs to give me permissions to that path so I can run `./adb devices`